# primeNG Angular - Page auto reload after dynamic dialog closes

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend, primeng

I was building a form component that is created by a button click on my page, which creates inside a dynamic dialog.

After the form is submitted, the form is updated to the server, but **the page immediately reloads after adding a '?' at the end of the URL** and I would like to stop it from happening.

I have tried removing the `onClose` subscription of the parent component and the same result happens, and the onClose related code is executed before reloading. Since the subscription is executed before reloading, I have no control of the settings of the component anymore.

The angular stack

- `primeng`: ^13.1.0
- `@angular/...`: ~13.1.0 except `@angular/cdk`: ^13.2.1

`parent.component.html`

```html
<button
  type="button"
  pButton
  icon="pi pi-plus"
  class="p-button-success mx-1"
  label="New"
  (click)="onAddNewEntry()"
></button>
```

`parent.component.ts`

```js
import { DialogService, DynamicDialogRef } from 'primeng/dynamicdialog';
import { ChildComponent } from './child-component';

@Component({
...
  providers: [DialogService]
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  constructor(
    private dialogService: DialogService
  ) {}

  ref: DynamicDialogRef = new DynamicDialogRef();

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  onAddNewEntry(): void {
    this.ref = this.dialogService.open(ChildComponent, {});
    this.ref.onClose.subscript(() => console.log('Hi'))
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    if (this.ref) {
      this.ref.close();
    }
  }
}
```

`child.component.ts`

```js
import { DynamicDialogConfig, DynamicDialogRef } from 'primeng/dynamicdialog';
@Component({
  ...
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private messageService: MessageService,
    private ref: DynamicDialogRef,
    private config: DynamicDialogConfig
  ) {}

  newEntryForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({});

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.newDeliverForm = new FormGroup({
      ...
    });
  }

  onSubmitNew() {
    //Handling
    this.ref.close(newDeliver);
  }
}
```

`app-routing.module.ts`

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'config',
    children: [
      { path: 'parent', component: ParentComponent },
    ],
  },
];
```

Comment: Currently, I have to disable the `this.ref.close()` command and manually close the dynamic dialog to avoid the auto page reload.

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem.  I tried Richard Mason's solution, which didn't work.  I removed *all* of the components in the popup (so now, it was popping up a blank dialog), but even then, it appeared briefly... then refreshed the entire page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was due to the default type of the button on the child component was `submit`, thus it submitted the child component form and make a query. After adding `type="button"` to the child component form, the issue is solved.

```html
<form [formGroup]="newDeliverForm">
  <!-- The form inputs -->
  <button
    *ngIf="!isEditMode"
    pButton
    type="button"
    label="Add"
    (click)="onSubmitNew()"
    icon="pi pi-plus"
    [disabled]="newDeliverForm.invalid"
  ></button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks mate, spent an entire day trying to figure out why this was happening.

Answer (score 0):

While submitting form, you should clearly mention the type of each button i.e. `type="button"` or `type="submit"`

```
<form>
   <button type="button" (click)="cancel()">Cancel</button>
   <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```